# In mapreduce, how does the "shuffle step" decides where should go each key?

Tags: mapreduce

Lets considere the basic word count example for a map reduce job and the following input:

```
word1
word2
word1
word2
word3
```

For our processing, we consider that we have three mappers and three reducers.

For the mapping, the data is processed as followed:

```
MAP1: (word1,1), (word2,1)
MAP2: (word1,1), (word2,1)
MAP3: (word3,1)
```

Now, the shuffle phase starts. `word1` keys need to be together, as well as `word2` and `word3` keys.

The shuffle phase could decide to send `word1` to `reducer1`, `word2` to `reducer2` and `word3` to `reducer3`, or `word1` to reducer2, etc.

**How is it decided which to which reducer will be shuffled each key ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before reduce step, hadoop uses implementation of `Partitioner` to determinate where key should be sent.
By default it is `HashPartitioner` with method:

```
public int getPartition(K key, V value, int numReduceTasks) {
    return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks;
}
```

You can use custom implementation if your job requires some additional logic:

```
job.setPartitionerClass(YourPartitioner.class)
```

Comment: Why is V in the prototype if it is not used in the body ?

Comment: @Itération122442 I think V is added to the method to let users of mapreduce framework to implement some custom logic depending on values. I can't show to you any example, but it maybe useful for somebody.